# AWS Cloudsearch CLI with --query-options throwing error

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a query which I am passing via the command line:

```
aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url http://myendpt search --search-query value --return _all_fields --cursor initial --size 100 --query-options {"defaultOperator":"or","fields":["id"],"operators":["and","escape","fuzzy","near","not","or","phrase","precedence","prefix","whitespace"]} --query-parser simple --query-parser simple --profile myname
```

It responds with:

```
Unknown options: operators:[and, escape, fuzzy, near, not, or, phrase, precedence, prefix, whitespace], fields:[id]
```

I assure you that `id` field exists in `AWS Cloudsearch`. I reverse engineered the query in the online cloudsearch query tester to AWS CLI.

Please help.

Update:

This problem has been resolved in the updated `aws-cli/1.8.4`. If you are a `ubuntu/linux` user like me:

please do:

```
sudo pip uninstall awscli
sudo pip install awscli
aws --version
```

Comment: Would you try a minimal example, starting with only a query term and then adding either 'fields' or 'operators'? It's easier to debug without all the additional, superfluous options.

Comment: And to save myself having to look it up again when I revisit this question, these are the relevant docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearchdomain/search.html

Comment: aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url http://myendpt search --search-query value --return _all_fields --cursor initial --size 100 --query-parser simple --query-parser simple --profile myname This works but no matter what I add after --query-options throws the same Unknow options error.

Comment: Yep this seems like a bug. I'm getting the same error using --query-options that I generated with the AWS web console. I also get an error _A client error (SearchException) occurred when calling the Search operation: q.options contains invalid javascript object_ if I have queryOptions with only a defaultOperator and no other options: `aws cloudsearchdomain search --search-query tree --endpoint-url http://search-mydomain.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com --query-options {"defaultOperator":"and"}`

Comment: Can you try the sdk because I am facing the same error there to.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the SDK and see what the `queryOptions` String is? I don't actually see a model for it (just a string) so I'm not sure serialization could be an issue; are you setting it via a String you created directly or is there some QueryOptions object I'm not seeing? I'm looking at the Java SDK https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/cloudsearchdomain/model/SearchRequest.java (I don't use the SDK or I'd try it out)

Comment: I am utilizing ruby. This worked: "{\"defaultOperator\":\"or\",\"fields\":[\"id\"],\"operators\":[\"and\",\"escape\",\"fuzzy\",\"near\",\"not\",\"or\",\"phrase\",\"precedence\",\"prefix\",\"whitespace\"]}"

Comment: Nice! Can't believe the AWS CLI doesn't do the escaping for you. Would you mind posting and accepting the solution you found? That will help the next person who comes along with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the Asker's solution from the comments: the issue is that you have to double-quote your json param, and then either single-quote (`'`) or escaped-double-quote (`\"`) the json key/values within your param.

For example, both of these are valid

```
--query-options "{'defaultOperator':'and','fields':['name']}"
```

or

```
--query-options "{\"defaultOperator\":\"and\",\"fields\":[\"name\"]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @alexroussos

Answer (score 4):

The solution for my ruby implementation of the `aws-sdk, ver > 2`

```
  client = Aws::CloudSearchDomain::Client.new(endpoint:'http://yoururl')
  resp = client.search({
                           cursor:"initial",
                           facet:"{\"facet_name_!\":{},\"mentions\":{}}",
                           query:"#{place_a_value_here}", 
                           query_options:"{\"defaultOperator\":\"or\",\"fields\":[\"yourfield\"],\"operators\":[\"and\",\"escape\",\"fuzzy\",\"near\",\"not\",\"or\",\"phrase\",\"precedence\",\"prefix\",\"whitespace\"]}",
                           query_parser:"simple",
                           return:"_all_fields",
                           size:1000,
                           highlight:"{\"text\":{}}",
                       })
```